# filter company based on category

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I was doing the project on Django to get into it more deeply. I have a problem in the model part. There are models; `Company`, `Product`, `Category`. `Company` is simply the introduction part. `Product` is about what product a company has and its divided into category which is `ManyToManyField`.

I have list all the categories in a page where if certain category is clicked then the list of companies that has product of that category should be filtered. But I don't know how to access it.

Here is my model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name='products', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    website = models.URLField(unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')


class Company(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='company')
    # product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='company')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the filter:

```
Company.objects.filter(products__categories__slug=category_slug)
```

where `category_slug` it is the value of your current select `Category.slug`

details:

1) if we need to get `Category`

```
cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)
```

2) if we need get all `Product` in this category

```
 product_list = Product.objects.filter(categories=cat)
```

or add double underscore to many2many models field name

```
 product_list = Product.objects.filter(categories__slug=cat)
 #                                               ^^^^
```

3) if need get `Company` for the product_list, filter by related_name of related model `Product` in the field FK on the `Company` `company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name='products'`

```
 Company.objects.filter(products__in=product_list)
 #                      ^^^^^^^
```

or by category instance

```
 cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)
 Company.objects.filter(products__categories=cat)
```

or finaly by category slug value

```
Company.objects.filter(products__categories__slug=category_slug)
```

Comment: So I should use the url like ``` <a href='/list/company?category=category.slug'>{{category.name}}</a> ``` then ?

Comment: I get the following error Cannot resolve keyword 'product' into field.

Comment: Sorry I missed the s in product. Can you explain me that chaining, please?

Comment: I must say this is the lucid explanation now. I appreciate your help, effort and explanation. Thank you

Comment: glad to help you!